# Why does cv2.SimpleBlobDetector outline extra whitespace only on one side of a blob?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV's cv2 module in Python 3, using SimpleBlobDetector to detect a single blob in an image snippet, but sometimes it incorrectly outlines extra whitespace only on one side, and therefore gives an incorrect centre point for the blob.

Here's an example image:

[Example blob with extra whitespace on top and left sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADE6u.png)

Here's a code snippet to show what I'm doing:

```
import numpy
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# img is a 2D numpy array containing an 8-bit grayscale image

img_area = img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.minArea = round(img_area / 4)
keypoints = detector.detect(img)

img_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

keypoint_coords = keypoints[0].pt
blob_center_coords = (round(keypoint_coords[1]), round(keypoint_coords[0]))
img_keypoints[blob_center_coords[0],blob_center_coords[1]] = (255,0,0) #places a red dot at the keypoint coordinates

imshow(image_keypoints)
plt.show()`
```

I'm guessing part of the problem is that the blob is against the edge of the image, but unfortunately, this is unavoidable in my analytical pipeline, so I need to be able to work around it. I've also tried playing with the SimpleBlobDetector params to no avail.

How do I make it shrink onto only the blob and ignore all that whitespace?

Comment: I do not think your "blob" is symmetric. It may look that way, but it is not in terms of the distribution of gray intensities.

Comment: [mre] required. please supply a minimal program including input data to reproduce the issue.